# Limiting value of the moment generating function

Tags: probability, self-study, moment-generating-function, geometric-distribution

Suppose that the discrete random variable $X_{n}$has a geometric distribution given by
$$f_{X_n}(x_n)=P_n{(1-P_n)}^{x_n}$$ where $$x_n={0,1,2,3,}$$ and $$P_n\ =\ \frac{\lambda}{n}$$ for $0<\lambda<n$. Find the limiting value of the moment-generating function of $Y_n= \frac{X_n}{n}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and use this result to determine the asymptotic distribution of $Y_n$.
I found this question in a book titled Exercises and Solutions in Statistical Theory (Exercise 3.23) and really appreciate it if you can help me.

Comment: I am unaware of such symbolism $f_{X_n}(X_n).$ It should be $f_{X_n}(x_n).$ Mainly you should show some attempts to solve the problem in hand and tell us where you stumbled in attempting the same.

Comment: @User1865345 thanks for your comment. I modified the symbolism but I do not have any idea about how to start.

Answer (score 1):

What should be the approach here?

We know if $X\sim \textrm{Geom}(p), ~M_X(t) = p(1-qe^t)^{-1}.$ Also we  know for a constant $c,~M_{cX}(t) = M_X(ct).$ Here $c $ should be $1/n.$

We can hope the limiting calculation could be implemented using elementary calculus techniques.

Can we now formally start to solve the problem? To see what happens? What could go wrong?

Comment: how t to determine the asymptotic distribution of $Y_n$

Comment: One approach would be to identify the distribution by inspection from $M_{Y_n}(t). $ The most general approach would be to use the [inversion formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462286/proof-of-inversion-theorem-for-characteristic-functions).